# How to scale target values of a Keras autoencoder model using a sklearn pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn pipelines to build a Keras autoencoder model and use gridsearch to find the best hyperparameters. This works fine if I use a Multilayer Perceptron model for classification; however, in the autoencoder I need the output values to be the same as input. In other words, I am using a `StandardScalar` instance in the pipeline to scale the input values and therefore this leads to my question: how can I make the `StandardScalar` instance inside the pipeline to work on both the input data as well as target data, so that they end up to be the same?

I'm providing a code snippet as an example.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adam
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor

X, y = make_classification (n_features = 50, n_redundant = 0, random_state = 0,
                            scale = 100, n_clusters_per_class = 1)

# Define wrapper
def create_model (learn_rate = 0.01, input_shape, metrics = ['mse']):
  model = Sequential ()
  model.add (Dense (units = 64, activation = 'relu',
                   input_shape = (input_shape, )))
  model.add (Dense (32, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add (Dense (8,  activation = 'relu'))
  model.add (Dense (32, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add (Dense (input_shape, activation = None))
  model.compile (loss = 'mean_squared_error',
                 optimizer = Adam (lr = learn_rate),
                 metrics = metrics)
  return model

# Create scaler
my_scaler = StandardScaler ()
steps = list ()
steps.append (('scaler', my_scaler))
standard_scaler_transformer = Pipeline (steps)

# Create classifier
clf = KerasRegressor (build_fn = create_model, verbose = 2)

# Assemble pipeline
# How to scale input and output??
clf = Pipeline (steps = [('scaler', my_scaler),
                         ('classifier', clf)],
                verbose = True)

# Run grid search
param_grid = {'classifier__input_shape' : [X.shape [1]],
              'classifier__batch_size' : [50],
              'classifier__learn_rate' : [0.001],
              'classifier__epochs' : [5, 10]}
cv = KFold (n_splits = 5, shuffle = False)
grid = GridSearchCV (estimator = clf, param_grid = param_grid,
                     scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', verbose = 1, cv = cv)
grid_result = grid.fit (X, X)

print ('Best: %f using %s' % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) to apply arbitrary transformations on the target values (i.e. `y`) by providing either a function (i.e. using `func` argument) or a transformer (i.e. `transformer` argument).

In this case (i.e. fitting an auto-encoder model), since you want to apply the same `StandardScalar` instance on the target values as well, you can use `transformer` argument. And it could be done in one of the following ways:

- You can use it as one of the pipeline steps, wrapping the regressor:

  ```
  scaler = StandardScaler()
  regressor = KerasRegressor(...)

  pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
      ('scaler', scaler),
      ('ttregressor', TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor, transformer=scaler))
  ])

  # Use `__regressor` to access the regressor hyperparameters
  param_grid = {'ttregressor__regressor__hyperparam_name' : ...}

  gridcv = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=param_grid, ...)
  gridcv.fit(X, X)
  ```
- Alternatively, you can wrap it around the `GridSearchCV` like this:

  ```
   ttgridcv = TransformedTargetRegressor(GridSearchCV(...), transformer=scalar)
   ttgridcv.fit(X, X)

   # Use `regressor_` attribute to access the fitted regressor (i.e. `GridSearchCV` instance) 
   print(ttgridcv.regressor_.best_score_, ttgridcv.regressor_.best_params_))
  ```

Comment: This seems to solve scaling the target. But now is it still possible to set parameters for the classifier inside the grid? When accessing `pipe.get_params ().keys ()` there are only parameters related to the new `TransformedTargetRegressor` object.

Comment: @kaylani2 Yes, I have mentioned in the code snippet using comments that you can access them using `__regressor` (see the line where I have set `param_grid`).

Comment: I see now. It looks odd not seeing the keys get returned by the pipeline, but this is just how sklearn has implemented. I'll accept the answer, today. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kaylani2 For me, running `pipe.get_params()` shows all the parameters including those of the regressor which is wrapped by `TransformedTargetRegressor`. More specifically, you can use `pipe['ttregressor'].get_params()`. Even you can go one step further and use `pipe['ttregressor'].regressor.get_params()` to only get the params of regressor.